# Getting the explorer values from a Google line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, linechart

I have a Google Line chart and I'm using the 'explorer' option to zoom in on the chart.

Once a user has zoomed in on a line chart i want to be able to get this selection.

Does anyone have any idea how?

Example chart: 
Once zoomed in I would like to get the selection.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
      data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

      data.addRows([
        [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
        [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
        [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
        [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
        [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        explorer: { 
                    actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
                    axis: 'horizontal',
                    keepInBounds: true,
                    maxZoomIn: 100
            },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following methods to determine the visible range of the chart

> `getChartLayoutInterface` -- Returns an object containing information about the onscreen placement of the chart and its elements.
>
> `getChartAreaBoundingBox` -- Returns an object containing the left, top, width, and height of the chart content.
>
> `getHAxisValue` - Returns the logical horizontal value at position, which is an offset from the chart container's left edge. Can be negative.
>
> `getVAxisValue` - Returns the logical vertical value at position, which is an offset from the chart container's top edge. Can be negative.

once you have the range you can filter the data table to find the relevant rows

see following working snippet...

there isn't a "zoom" event, so a `MutationObserver` is used to detect zoom...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');
    data.addRows([
      [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
      [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
      [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
      [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
      [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
      [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
      [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
      [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
      [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
      [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
      [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
      [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
      [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
      [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
        subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
      },
      explorer: {
        actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 100
      },
      pointSize: 6,
      theme: 'maximized',
      width: 900,
      height: 500
    };

    var container = $('#chart_div').get(0);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

    // detect zoom
    var visibleRange = {};
    var zoomObserver = new MutationObserver(checkZoom);
    zoomObserver.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);

    function checkZoom() {
      var newRange = getChartRange();
      if (JSON.stringify(visibleRange) !== JSON.stringify(newRange)) {
        visibleRange = newRange;
        showRangeValues();
      }
    }

    function getChartRange() {
      var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
      var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
      return {
        x: {
          min: chartLayout.getHAxisValue(chartBounds.left),
          max: chartLayout.getHAxisValue(chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width)
        },
        y: {
          min: chartLayout.getVAxisValue(chartBounds.top + chartBounds.height),
          max: chartLayout.getVAxisValue(chartBounds.top)
        }
      };
    }

    function showRangeValues() {
      var rangeFilter;
      var rangeKey;
      var rangeRows;
      var rangeTable;
      var rangeView;

      rangeFilter = [];
      $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns()), function (colIndex) {
        rangeKey = (colIndex === 0) ? 'x' : 'y';
        rangeFilter.push({
          column: colIndex,
          minValue: visibleRange[rangeKey].min,
          maxValue: visibleRange[rangeKey].max
        });
      });

      rangeRows = data.getFilteredRows(rangeFilter);
      rangeView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      rangeView.setRows(rangeRows);
      $('#range_div').html(rangeRows.length + ' of ' + data.getNumberOfRows() + ' rows...');

      rangeTable = new google.visualization.Table($('#table_div').get(0));
      rangeTable.draw(rangeView);
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="range_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!